# Which approach to offer multilingual app in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, multilingual

In Android it's easy to make an app multilingual. What bothers me is that I'm not sure how to offer such an App in Google Play. That means:

- Should the name and the description of the app in English plus a
  German translation only for description. The app itself takes care about multilingualism. But will people who cannot speak English find the app?
- Should I offer two separate apps, one English, one German. I think
  this is very cumbersome, because it's very difficult to add more
  languages in future and the more languages I use the more time
  consuming is release and maintenance. The good thing is that there is a German app name and description and an English app name and description. But imagine I have a PRO and LITE version too.

I tend to use possibility one. How do people usually solve this? What is the best "standard language" for the app to reach the most people? In Google Play Developer I see that English language is used at about 13%. German only 8%. So it should be wise to use English as standard language. Is this the usual way to do that or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best standard language for virtually all cases is obviously English. Largest user base and most common as a 2nd language.

Anyway, you can make description and most other things in the Google Play Developer console multilingual. You first select the standard language and add as many other secondary languages as you like. Thus, you can have one app that has an English and a German name! Users with a German locale will find the app under the German name and English users will find the English name.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that I'm able to create the whole app entry in Developer Console with different languages, including pictures, description an name. That explains it.